# Como unir 4 listas y asignar 1 valor? En python

Tags: python, diccionarios, zip

```
nombres = ["Martín", "Milú", "Anastasia", "Lupita", "Tomasa", "Pelusa", "Genoveva", "Motita"]
tipos = ["canino", "canino", "felino", "felino", "felino", "canino", "bovino","roedor"]
edades = [12, 9, 10, 8, 9, 2,14,1]
pesos = [33, 26, 4, 5, 5, 6, 106.4, 0.34]
x1 = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
```

Hola, llevo poco tiempo programando y se me formula este problema. Debo hacer que la variable x1 quede ubicada en un diccionario como clave y las demás listas como valor. Donde la posición 0 debe ir con la posición 0 de tipo como también la de edades y pesos. Así sucesivamente. al final debo imprimir

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradecería si me pudieses explicar formas de poner unir este tipo de ejercicio gracias

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya hice un primer intento de esta forma donde me imprime el resultado que espero pero quiero saber si hay mas formas de realizarlo. Gracias

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, por favor incluye el código con lo que has intentado, las preguntas que solicitan que alguien resuelva la tarea/ejercicio/proyecto sin mostrar ningún esfuerzo no son bien recibidas y por lo general terminan cerradas y/o con puntos negativos. Por favor edita la pregunta e incluye la información que hace falta. Saludos

Comment: `dicc = {x1[i]: [nombres[i], tipos[i], edades[i], pesos[i]] for i in range(len(nombres))}`

Answer (score 0):

La forma de unir varias lista en una única lista que contiene los elementos de un mismo índice en una tupla es con `zip()`:

De modo que para poner todos los valores en una lista de tuplas de la siguiente forma:

```
[('Martín', 'canino', 12, 33), ('Milú', 'canino', 9, 26), ('Anastasia', 'felino', 10, 4), ('Lupita', 'felino', 8, 5), ('Tomasa', 'felino', 9, 5), ('Pelusa', 'canino', 2, 6), ('Genoveva', 'bovino', 14, 106.4), ('Motita', 'roedor', 1, 0.34)]
```

utilizamos:

```py
values=[list(x) for x in zip(nombres,tipos,edades,pesos)]
```

obteniendo:

```
[['Martín', 'canino', 12, 33], ['Milú', 'canino', 9, 26], ['Anastasia', 'felino', 10, 4], ['Lupita', 'felino', 8, 5], ['Tomasa', 'felino', 9, 5], ['Pelusa', 'canino', 2, 6], ['Genoveva', 'bovino', 14, 106.4], ['Motita', 'roedor', 1, 0.34]]
```

Repetimos lo mismo una vez más con las claves de diccionario y convertimos a diccionario:

```py
dict(zip(x1,values))
```

Resultando en:

```py
{'1': ['Martín', 'canino', 12, 33], '2': ['Milú', 'canino', 9, 26], '3': ['Anastasia', 'felino', 10, 4], '4': ['Lupita', 'felino', 8, 5], '5': ['Tomasa', 
'felino', 9, 5], '6': ['Pelusa', 'canino', 2, 6], '7': ['Genoveva', 'bovino', 14, 106.4], '8': ['Motita', 'roedor', 1, 0.34]}
```

`dict(arra1,array2)` toma como par `key,value` los elementos del mismo índice de sus respectivas listas.

```
myDict = {
array1[0]:array2[0],
array1[1]:array2[1],
array1[2]:array2[2],
...
}
```